# FontAwesome with twitter bootstrap general questions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, less, retina-display, font-awesome

I have some general questions about the use of Font Awesome with Twitter Bootstrap.

I used the LESS integration method described on their website.

1. I thought it was an "iconic" font. So why does it change the main text font provided with Twitter Bootstrap? Can I prevent this behavior?
2. Icons really look blurry compared to the Glyphicon png version provided with twitter bootstrap, especially at smaller sizes. Why?
3. What is the solution for displaying icons correctly (using Twitter Bootstrap) on both standard and retina displays?

Thanks for any input.

Edit: Here is an example of the issues I am having.

[image: Font Awesome issues]

As you can see, the font looks different after installing Font Awesome. The buttons shape and feel is lost. The green and red buttons' icons have been rendered using icon-large, but they still look very blurry. Further to this, I realize now that it just somehow screwed my design.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using font awesome on my site, and been loving it.. I dont see anywhere that it messes with the font on the page, so for that point Id have to see an example of what you're talking about..
some of the icons are really blurry when when they get smaller, and theres no way around that one except to make them bigger with the icon-large class. this is because of the scale the font awesome guy made them at
I've been putting all the icons in its own element when I use em - `<em class="icon-thumbs-up></em>` and then putting the text after or before that.. and as far as i know, the icons work on all browsers mobile and desktop except for opera mini because mini doesnt support the font-face property

I've also been looking at http://icomoon.io/app/ for icons, though I havent tried them out yet. I am planning on day switching font-awesome to that, but its gonna take a little while as I have a lot on my table as it stands now.

Comment: I edited my post to illustrate the issues I am talking about. Thanks for the icomoon stuff. I will look into this. Any idea on how to integrate it with Twitter Bootstrap? Cheers.

Comment: I see what you mean with the blurryness, and theres really no way around that one that I know of unless you have bootstraps icons in there to. If you do adding `[class*="icon-] {background:none;}` might help. One thing to keep in mind is they are not the glyphicons that bootstrap uses, its a different icon all together which is why they're different

and then for the icomoon app, once you select the icons you want to use and download it, you'll get the css file along with a sample html page with the icons on it.. then it just using it the same way you would use font awesome

Comment: That icomoon app http://icomoon.io/app is really great! It allows you to select only the icons you need, import your own art, download it as png or as a font. And it even gives you all the CSS you need to integrate to your own app. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Font-Awesome is heavily using selectors containing `[class^="icon-"]`. This could cause issues if you for some reason use classes that start with `icon-` elsewhere. Bootstrap does the same but probably doesn't set margins and font-size for its icons.

Comment: I do not use any custom class starting with "icon-".

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yeah it was just a wild guess. Maybe you should try looking at the css rules in use with Firebug (or similar build-in browser tools) to see where the differences come from. Also check if LESS is compiled correctly, I know some implementations screw up on multiple imports.

Comment: I will follow your advice regarding debugging. Thank you.